# The first eigenvalue for Dirichlet boundary condition positive?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $M$ be a compact, n dimensional Riemannian manifold with boundary. Then we know that $W^{1,2}(M)=W^{1,2}_0(M)$, the latter is the completion of $C_0^{\infty}(M)$ function w.r.t $W^{1,2}(M)$-norm.  We know that the first eigenvalue for Dirichlet boundary problem is
$$
\lambda_1^D=\inf\{\frac{\int |\nabla f|^2}{\int |f^2|}| f \in W^{1,2}_0(M)\}
$$
Since $1\in W^{1,2}(M)=W^{1,2}_0(M)$, We have $\lambda_1^D=0$. I have seen in some books that $\lambda_1^D>0$. So I am confused.

And since $W^{1,2}(M)=W^{1,2}_0(M)$, then $\lambda_k^D=\lambda_k^N$ (Neumann boundary condition) by the Rayleigh's formula?

Comment: Is $W^{1,2}_0(M)$ the completion of $C^\infty_0(M)$ or $C^\infty_0(\text{int} M)$?

Comment: If the manifold has boundary, then $W^{1,2}(M) \neq W_0^{1,2}(M)$ and $1$ does not belong to $W_0^{1,2}(M)$ (it doesn't satisfy the appropriate boundary conditions). If the manifold doesn't have boundary, then indeed $1$ is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.